# SQL table to JSON file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can I make this piece of code i have to generate a JSON file for me?

Right now I read the values into a string, but I want it to generate the file automatically.

```
 using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
 {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
            userinfo info = new userinfo();

            info.userid = reader.GetInt32(0);
            info.username = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            info.password = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            info.firstname = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            info.lastname = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            info.dob = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            info.dateregistered = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            jsonString = jss.Serialize(info);
           //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);
      }
 }
```

Comment: You tagged this as `json.net` but your code is using the built in serializer. Which do you want the answer to use?

Comment: Are you asking how save string into a file?

Comment: I am sorry the serializer.

Comment: Do you want one file per record or all records from db should be serialized to json and placed into one file?

Comment: Yes all files from the db should serialized to one json file.

Comment: It seems like you want to store and serialize a `List<userinfo>` rather than serializing each one.

Comment: do you need the client side coding to generate a json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a list of userinfo. Then you can serialize that list and save it to file.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      List<userinfo> infoList = new List<userinfo>();
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        userinfo info = new userinfo();

        info.userid = reader.GetInt32(0);
        info.username = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
        info.password = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
        info.firstname = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
        info.lastname = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
        info.dob = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
        info.dateregistered = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();

        infoList.Add(info);

  }
  var jsonSerialiser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
  string jsonString = jsonSerialiser.Serialize<(infoList);
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\userlist.json", jsonString);

}
```

For read back

```
jsonSerialiser.Deserialize<List<userinfo>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\userlist.json"));
```

Answer (score 3):

This code below iterates over each reader value and add them to a Dictionary, which is added to a List.

The Dictionary will be serialized as an object in JSON and the List will be serialized as an array.

```
string json = string.Empty;
List<object> objects = new List<object>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                IDictionary<string, object> record = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    record.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
                }
                objects.Add(record);
            }
        }
    }
}
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create("C:\\path\\file.json")))
{
    sw.Write(json);
}
```

Comment: I get the same value as I previously got but this does not create a json file for me. understand I am very new to this and have zero understanding. I need these values to form a json file. is it possible?

Comment: I will test it once I get to school I'm on my way there. But it seems to be the answer.